# Addon to modify http headers specified via regex of content

Tags: regex, firefox, http-headers, firefox-addon

I need a Firefox addon that would enable me to modify outbound http request headers thusly:

```
"[pseudocode] if any request header contains x in its content then replace x with y"
```

where x is a regular expression and y preferably can contain substitution patterns referencing x.

I've looked at the addons `Tamper Data` `Modify Headers` and `Header Tool` and none of them appear to support the above (Am I wrong?)  "Header Tool" has some regex capability, but not apparently as specified above.  Would `greasemonkey` or the like enable this?  The only problem in my case is that the http request is actually sent out via an .swf (i.e. flash), though it is still displayed by say `Tamper Data`

(Note: If you think this query doesn't belong at stackoverflow, then please reference what stackexchange to use (though who other than programmers would be messing with reg expressions).  This also isn't something to google, as 
the first thing it returns is Header Tool which doesn't do what I want.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361720/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-in-just-one-tab-of-firefox/22370569#22370569

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly trivial to write such an addon yourself if you don't need any GUI.

The SDK has a module ([system-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_events)) that requires only a few lines of code to hook into any and all [HTTP requests or responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests)

Comment: Thanks,  that would be great, too.  Knew something like that had to exist. Otoh, with Burp the solution would work regardless of browser, but will look in to what you describe.  Incidentally, am working on a solution to foil browser fingerprinting via rewriting headers, post data, etc. that contain unique system info.  Don't have credentials to upvote yet.  This forum has really changed.

Answer (score 0):

Burp is not an FF addon but instead a java app but even the free version of it easily does what I described.

Comment: A firefox addon to do this would be TamperData: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/?src=search