# Chrome extension to check a link and redirect to another website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building one extension in which i want to block some website urls from my chrome/firefox browser.

Lets say that i have a list of URLS that i want to make it a blacklist.
So whenever the chrome user wants to join them, the extension will redirect to another URL of my choice (inside the code i will determine which URL i want it to be)

Through some research i managed to make for CHROME this one

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "name": "URL Block",
    "description": "Redirect to another site",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
                    "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
            "*://apple.com/*",
            "*://www.apple.com/*",
            "*://iptorrents.com/*",
            "*://www.iptorrents.com/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

***background.js***

```
var host = "http://www.google.com";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
            "*://apple.com/*",
            "*://www.apple.com/*",
            "*://iptorrents.com/*",
            "*://www.iptorrents.com/*"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

So this extension works perfect for what im trying to do.
But now i have some questions.

QUESTION:

***Lets say that i want the extension to redirect to 2 different URL
 (and not only in google.com as in my example above.)
[Which means, when i put URL: www.facebook.com and press the enter, the extension will redirect the certain tab to www.google.com AND OPEN A NEW TAB to redirect to www.abc.com]***

Comment: Yes, please make a separate question for firefox an **highlight** your actual question. See ["How to Ask" guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You already did a good job salvaging the question, but it needs a little push to be cleanly answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in chrome but with firefox you do it like this:

[How can I change the User Agent in just one tab of Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361720/how-can-i-change-the-user-agent-in-just-one-tab-of-firefox/22370569#22370569) in that solution instead of `httpChannel.setRequestHeader` do `httpChannel.redirectTo` you can read about redirectTo here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel#redirectTo%28%29

Comment: and where do i put the urls that i want to block?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios in the solution I linked to, you have to test the `httpChannel.URI.spec` see this other very similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25328750/1828637

Answer (score 1):

You can both redirect a tab *and* open a new one, which seems like what you're trying to achieve.

It's as simple as this (in the `onBeforeRequest` listener):

```
function(details) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "your 2nd URL",
    active: true // Change to false if you want it to open in the background
                 // and see the docs for more options
  });
  return {redirectUrl: "your 1st URL" };
}
```

However, you probably don't want to open a new tab *every time* a URL is accessed. Note your `types` declaration:

```
types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
```

That means every time *any* page tries to load a resource from those sites, you'll get a new tab popping up. So, it's best to filter by type:

```
function(details) {
  if(details.type == "main_frame") {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "your 2nd URL",
      active: true
    });
  }
  return {redirectUrl: "your 1st URL" };
}
```

Comment: I put the second code inside the `onBeforeRequest` listener, replace the urls where you mention but i have some problems
1) it opens a new tab but its not redirecting to the page, but in this link here 
[link](chrome-extension://fkecblnphpabincjjhiognoobljgjpli/www.abc.com)

when i try to add abc.com to the 2nd url.

2) the first tab is joining the page that im trying to block.

Comment: `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
  if(details.type == "main_frame") {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "www.abc.com",
      active: true
    });
  }
  return {redirectUrl: "www.abc.com" };
},
    {
        urls: [
            "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
 "*://apple.com/*",
            "*://www.apple.com/*",
   "*://iptorrents.com/*",
            "*://www.iptorrents.com/*"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);`

Comment: and i want to open a new tab whenever i try to go to a blacklisted URL. Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Comment: In general, you should make a new question for such code dumps. You need to specify the protocol for `www.abc.com`, make it a full url. If you still have questions post a new one.

Comment: My question is the same as my post. since the code that you posted is not working for me, is it working for you? thats all i ask about your answer